# Streamlining the process of running multiple requests at once

Tags: php, multithreading, simple-html-dom

I have plans for a website which clunkily enough needs to scrape multiple websites at once. I'm thinking of how I can make that as fast as possible, but I don't really know how.

I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to scrape a few websites for certain items. It looks something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html($fullUrl);

$collection = $html->find('div.info');
```

If I wanna scrape multiple sites at once, can I streamline the scraping process by branching it out  to different PHP-documents, perhaps with separate `simple_html_dom.php` documents? Where page A makes one request to page B and C each, which individually return data to page A. Will they run simultaneously or just queue up?

I've looked in to PHP-multithreading, and come to the conclusion that it's yet a little bit advanced, and I don't quite understand how to implement the existing templates to my particular code setup.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By multiple websites at once, do you mean to scrape multiple websites on single request?

Comment: I mean, multiple requests or single requests are both viable options to me. Yes, multiple sites. I want X info from site B and Y info from site C. Scraping just feels really clunky, you know.

Comment: Maybe try this? https://github.com/duzun/hQuery.php Not sure exactly what you're asking though.

Comment: in PHP your asynchronous options are curl_multi and Guzzle (which actually is a wrapper for cutl_multi). I suppose you could try to hack something with threads but it's probably a real bad idea. You could also choose a different language, Node is a good fit for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would definitely look into parallel processing in PHP regardless of what you perceive to be "advanced"

Here is some pseudocode of the general idea:

```
while(hasMoreSitesForScrapingInQueue){
     if(numOfCurrentlyRunningProcesses < maxNumberOfProcesses){
          // create new process that invokes file_get_html() and completes associated logic
     }
}
```